# Cookie intermittently loses values in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

An error has cropped up on our site (PHP/Linux/Apache) where the $_COOKIE global variable loses all its values on certain pages. This is usually after either following a link with GET parameters or submitting a POST form. I'm really puzzled as to why this has suddenly started occuring. To illustrate, I have dumped out the values of the $_COOKIE variable on each page as I navigate through the site (some values replaced by xxx).

Home page (all fine):

```
Array
(
    [nav-hosting] => 1
    [nav-server_management] => 1
    [locale] => en-US
    [psaContext] => tools
    [mycart] => xxx
    [myid] => xxx
    [__utma] => xxx
    [__utmb] => xxx
    [__utmc] => xxx
    [__utmz] => xxx
)
```

Results page after submitting site search form (all fine):

```
Array
(
    [nav-hosting] => 1
    [nav-server_management] => 1
    [locale] => en-US
    [psaContext] => tools
    [mycart] => xxx
    [myid] => xxx
    [__utma] => xxx
    [__utmb] => xxx
    [__utmc] => xxx
    [__utmz] => xxx
)
```

Click through to a page from the search results (problem occurs):

```
Array
(
    [1] => 
)
```

So, the $_COOKIE inexplicably has an index of 1 with a null value. Can anyone suggest what might be causing this?

A further click from that last page with the problem will resume all the original values again. Baffling!

Comment: Please post some code, like how you grap the cookie on every page. It is almost impossible to help with only the result =)

Comment: Use your browser's Developer Tools (all major browsers have them) to make sure that the `Cookie` and related headers are being sent/received on every request.  For the request where the cookie data is not being sent, see if a *different* `SetCookie` header is received from the server (or none at all).

Comment: Accessing cookie:

`if (isset($_COOKIE['myid'])) {
 // do something with $_COOKIE['myid']
}`

Setting cookie:

`setcookie('myid', $_COOKIE['myid'], time()+60*60*24, "/", ".".str_replace("www.","",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])); // 24 hours`

Comment: I will look at the browser's development tools too

Answer (score 0):

As you did not provide any code, I´ll guess: Are you on another subdomain, or moved out of the path where your cookie is valid?

Comment: No to both, it's all happening on the same domain, no subdomains, and the cookie is valid from the root.